# Need to place text files using batch

Tags: batch-file

I want to place multiple text files using batch script from the current folder to a folder in program files. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Open a Command Prompt window, type `copy /?`, press the `[ENTER]` key, and read the output. Optionally you could also do the same with `%SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe /?`, and `%SystemRoot%\System32\Robocopy.exe /?`. Please in future use the search facility, at the top of the page, or your preferred search engine for non-coded problem questions such as this.

Answer (score 0):

My personal favourite is `xcopy`, you can use is like this:

```
xcopy /F *.txt "C:\Program Files\"
```

The `/F` is very useful because it shows you how your files get copied, something like:

```
C:\Temp_Folder\.Net_Version.txt -> C:\Program Files\.Net_Version.txt
C:\Temp_Folder\1.txt -> C:\Program Files\1.txt
C:\Temp_Folder\conf.conf.txt -> C:\Program Files\conf.conf.txt
C:\Temp_Folder\DLL_List.txt -> C:\Program Files\DLL_List.txt
C:\Temp_Folder\DLL_List_gekuist.txt -> C:\Program Files\DLL_List_gekuist.txt
C:\Temp_Folder\DNA.txt -> C:\Program Files\DNA.txt
```

Be aware that `C:\Program Files\` is a protected directory, you'll need administrator rights for performing the copy (put the `xcopy` command in a batchfile and launch it as administrator (right click)):

[image]