# Running as administrator in Windows

Tags: python, windows

I'm trying to write basic program with Python. I'm typing Windows commands with os library. Because of that, it doesn't work and wants to be admin. There was being superuser with a command in Linux(sudo). I couldn't find any way to run my program as administrator. I tried wmic and got an error named "Alias not found". Are there any way to run program as administrator?

Comment: if you right click and executable you should have an option "Run as administrator". Otherwise open a cmd console as admin and anything you run from there will be as admin.

Comment: See my answer on another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71841719/need-to-place-text-files-using-batch/71841830#71841830

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. It doesn't work through IDE. It worked after running file from cmd as administrator. Problem solved but I'm having new trouble. It gives an error such as "netsh Alias not found". In short, I can't process with wmic. What can I do? Should I ask a new question? Otherwise, is asking question here okay?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to make a program run in admin mode(the short handle we use for windows). If the object is an executable file or type of script and a few other file types I am not 100% certain of the extensive list. You would just right-click the file and select run as admin mode. If you are trying to run your program in admin mode I do believe that if you make python run as admin mode all the time your .py files should inherit the administrative privileges I would need someone to clarify that though. I am slightly confused as to your question though, as you say typing commands in os library are referring to the CMD(Command Prompt)?

Edit: In case you were referring to CMD open the start menu and type CMD and Right click and open as admin mode.